# Where is my dependency injection going wrong in my angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, gruntjs, yeoman

To begin with

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute'
])
```

Here is my casual factory. Nothing really to see

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('myFactory', function () {
    // Service logic
    // ...

    // Public API here
    return {
      isSaved: true
    };
  });
```

Here is a controller I use the service in. There is one more like this. They both follow the same pattern

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('AdvertisersCtrl', [ '$scope', '$location', 'myFactory', function ($scope, $location, myFactory) {
    $scope.$emit('controllerChange', 2);

    $scope.isFormSave = function () {
      // Form Validation
      myFactory.isSaved = true;
      $location.path('/saved');
    };
  }]);
```

And last, but certainly not least. The error I am getting.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myFactoryProvider <- myFactory
http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=myFactoryProvider
```

Also, this project was scaffolded with yoeman, and it uses ngmin.. and all the other packaged grunt tasks yoeman provides.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Are they in different files?

Comment: yeah, every service/controller/directive is in its own file

Comment: any thoughts @victorczm ?

Comment: In what order are you loading the files? Try this: put the module declaration in one file (app.js), the controller in one, and the service in another. Load app.js first. Also, try to provide a plunkr or something similar, even if it's broken. Helps to look at how you are structuring your code.

Comment: I'm essentially loading my modules, app.js, controllers, then services. I remember putting services before controllers and it not making a difference. Maybe that is the issue though? @victorczm

Answer (score 0):

Do you create the module `app` ?
In the code snippets above both invocations of `module()` are supposed to retrieve instance of already existing module.
But you have to create it first.

`angular.module('app', [])` vs. `angular.module('app')`

more info: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval

Comment: yep, it's created. sorry i forgot to add it